# Fetching content from a form, should I check for undefined or null or?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do this:

```
var text = $("#some-input-box").val();


// check for null/empty string
if(text == null || text = undefined || text.length == 0 ) {

}
```

I want check for all cases if the value returned is null or empty string etc.

What should I be checking for here?

Is it a good idea to make a generic function that returns true/false if the text is empty or null or undefined ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for any invalid data, to make sure the user doesn't put something in that breaks some other functionality.

Maybe the validation plugin?

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 0):

you can try out validation plugins like

```
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
```

Or

```
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/
```